# Resources for camping in Georgia (country)

Tags: safety, camping, resources, georgia

Is there any resource provided by the Georgian government or by any other agencies about the camping in Georgia? I would like to know about the rules and safety aspects.

Any resource on these would help.

Comment: "Wild camping is also largely accepted and often asking for a good place for your tent you will find a comfortable bed, couch, plenty of food and alcohol. Pitching a tent is a normal thing for the local people, forbidden only in city centres and near ruins." Source: http://nomadwiki.org/en/Georgia_(country)

Comment: Are you speaking about camping in wildness? As you're asking about this - don't do it. There are no national parks with rangers or proximity of everything to some populated areas or something like this. You can't be prepared by booklet for real steppe wildness or conflicts. Also, you aren't allowed to cross the border with something that has a chance to repel wolfs' pack or locals, for example. However, you can look for their resorts near the capital, they're somewhat safe. Also, you can hire a local guide for your camping trip in the steppe.

Comment: About rules - almost no rules if this isn't a town or a restricted place, you're on your own. As the first point... nothing like parks in the US or Europe.

Comment: http://en.traveltogeorgia.com.ge/gid.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [website](https://www.geocamp.ge/) of some private travel agency. I would try to message them in IG. https://www.instagram.com/geocamp_ge/ 
FYI, they offer camping trips at The Black Sea, not sure about mountain camping.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of the national parks of Georgia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_parks_of_Georgia_(country)

Here is the link to the ecotourism section of the Georgian Agency of Protected Areas.  This has information about the areas, trails and camping in the various areas.

http://apa.gov.ge/en/eco-tourism